# Function stacking, nesting, order of handling

Tags: python, function, debugging

Old dawg, coding experience goes way back, to the age of GoTo statements (Especially in automation scripts.) Python is Structured and (choke) "old habits" are nul. So.... An exercise to better grok a.) Functions and b.) Global variables.

1. What's the best practice (convention) for inserting debug stops that cite line numbers whilst pausing execution?
2. Brief me / thumbnail on function stacking, nesting, order of handling... is execution strictly sequential?

```
# Hello World.
# Featuring recursive interactive Keyboard I/O
# Author ...dgg
# ______________________________________________
#
#Function Definitions

# Print "Hello, world!" on the screen:
def hello():
    print("Hello, World!")

# Ask the user if they want to play game and collect answer
def qplay_game():
    global answer
    print('If you want to play a game Press "y" and then return 
key...')
    print('To decline: quit, press "q" and then the return 
key...')
    answer = input()

# The user declines to play so say they quit and return their 
input.    
def decl_game():
    print('Okay, goodbye! You said declined to play = ' + answer)  

# The user doesn't want to play again so say they quit and return 
their input.    
def end_game():
    print('Okay, goodbye! You said quit = ' + game)   

# The Game: Ask the user for their name and collect answer
def start_game():
    print('What is your name?')
    # Get the user's name from their keyboard input:
    name = input()
    # Greet the user by their name:
    print('Hello, ' + name)
    print('Thanks for playing.')

# Ask if user wants to play again        
def continue_game():        
    print('Would you like to play again? Press "y" for yes or "q" 
for quit.')
    game = input()
    if game == 'y': start_game()
    elif game == 'q': end_game()

#Program Main
hello()
qplay_game()
if answer == 'y':
    start_game()
    qplay_game()
elif answer == 'q':
    decl_game()
continue_game()
```

The code runs but halts. And I wasn't expecting the recursive question in the middle.

Comment: Hi David.  Welcome to stackoverflow. There are various formatting tools for questions that you should use.  It's called Markdown. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Usually the IDE is not important and we want to see the code itself. Also, check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to write a question. Not saying your question is wrong, just might need a bit more work. Also, no need to mention the urgency.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question.  I'd remove the code images though or people will just downvote your question.  You can also show the code output as text.

Comment: Righto, done. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609514/bill

Answer (score 0):

Welcome back to programming, in 2023!

I also started with Basic in the early 1980's and recently got back into programming with Python.  There are a lot of similarities ... and differences.

**Response to Question 2**

Firstly, no GOTO statements!  Flow control is handled solely by code blocks and flow control structures such as if, for, while, and with.

As explained [here](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/), functions are self-contained blocks of code that encapsulate a specific task or related group of tasks. However, they cannot be used as a replacement for goto. After execution, control is returned to the same place from where the function was called. The order in which the functions were defined is not important.

So in your example script, to make the game repeat you would have to do something like this:

```
# Program main
hello()
while True:
    start_game()
    qplay_game()
    if answer == 'q':
        break
    continue_game()
    if answer == 'q':
        break

decl_game()
```

**Response to Question 1**

I'm not sure about best practices for debugging. You can either use your IDEs built-in debugger (if it has one) or Python's default debugger (using the `breakpoint()` function).  Maybe start with the latter. Here is one [guide to Python's default debugger](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/). Try it out and post if you have specific questions.

**Global variables**

B.t.w. your use of the global variable `answer` seems fine. However, best practice is to avoid global variables except in specific situations.  For example, you could redefine your `qplay_game`  function to return the answer as follows:

```
def qplay_game():
    # your code here
    return input()
```

And then call it as follows inside your game loop:

```
    answer = qplay_game()
```

This makes it more explicit what it does.

Comment: It may also be worth checking out the **logging** module which allows warning, info, debug etc messages to be actioned at suitable points and unlike using print statements can be simply all be switched on or off by level. **try...except** blocks, **raise** and **assert** can also be used for critical errors.

Comment: @user19077881 I would argue that for someone learning Python for the first time, using the logging module is not necessary. I would even argue that using print statements for debugging in the early stages is fine.

Comment: @Bill - I agree. But maybe useful to know there are other ways even if only for future consideration.

Comment: Genuinely appreciate you folks sharing your wisdom... very helpful. The logging module is something I'll be exploring next. Cool.

Comment: "After execution, control is returned to the same place from where the function was called. The order in which the functions were defined is not important."  FYI, this was super helpful. Some other things I noodled make sense in this context. Thank you.